# How to permanently delete values from the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I have a method that i call from a javascript, the method suppose to delete the records permanently but it does not go in to the method if the method has `DataContext db = new DataContext();`, it gives the error `Internal Server Error`

```
public void PermanantlyDeleteComment(GetCommentInput input)
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext();
    //Follow by the code to delete the comment
}
```

If i comment out `DataContext db = new DataContext();` the breakpoint does go in.

I think the problem is with the datacontext but i do know know where

Here is the datacontext

```
public DataContext() : base("name=Default")
{
    this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
}
```

I'm using DataContext because abp boilerplate does not want to permanently delete, only soft delete, if you have a way that i can hard delete with boilerplate please let me know.

Comment: Use your browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response, which will contain the details of the exception

Comment: Don't just randomly comment/un-comment code, *find out what the error is*.  When you debug, is the method invoked?  As you step through in the debugger, what happens?  Where does it fail?  What is the exception?  You need to know what the error *is* before you can correct it.  Randomly guessing isn't going to get you anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the `DataContext` was correct, is just i had different `EntityFramework` version on my  Database Library (which has `DataContext.cs`) and my Web Library

Answer (score 0):

Answered in this topic: https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=6180#p6193

> You can override CancelDeletionForSoftDelete method in your DbContext and prevent cancellation conditionally.

So, like this:

```
protected override void CancelDeletionForSoftDelete(EntityEntry entry)
{
    if (IsSoftDeleteFilterEnabled)
    {
        base.CancelDeletionForSoftDelete(entry);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public void PermanantlyDeleteComment(GetCommentInput input)    
{
    using (CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.SoftDelete))
    {
        // The code to delete the comment
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the code works but now it disable softdelete for everything in the system, i wanted to prevent softdelete on 1 page. I have only 1 place that i wanted hard delete not the whole system.

Comment: That disables in the `using` block only.

Comment: on using , when i use DisableFilter or EnableFilter it hard delete

Comment: That's what you asked for.