# The method is not kicking in if there is DataContext

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, aspnetboilerplate

Good day

i'm trying to hard delete a soft deleted records, i have a Method `Task PermanantlyDeleteDeal(GetDealInput input)` When i call the method it does not go in.

Since boilerplate 0.9.6 is not hard deleting, i'm now using `Database>DataContext.cs` class to execute hard delete

Here is my DataContext class

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Deal> Deal{ get; set; }   

    public DataContext()
       : base("Default")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }}
```

Here is the function on javaScript that u call the method

```
function DeleteLead(btnCaller) {
abp.message.confirm('Lead will be deleted.', 'Are you sure?', function (isConfirmed) {
    if (isConfirmed) {
        var button = $(btnCaller);
        var proposalId = button.data('content');
        var proposalObject = Object({
            Id: proposalId
        });
        abp.ui.setBusy();
        _leadService.permanantlyDeleteLead(proposalObject).done(function (result) {
            abp.notify.success('Successfully deleted a proposal', 'Quotation deleted');
            Refresh();
        }).always(function () {
            abp.ui.clearBusy();
        });
    }
});
```

}

Here is the PermanantlyDeleteComment

```
public async Task PermanantlyDeleteDeal(GetDealInput input)
    {
        UserFriendlyException ufex = null;
        try
        {
            DataContext db = new DataContext();

            using (Repository.Repository<Deal> repo = new Repository.Repository<Deal>(db))
            {
                using (Repository.Repository<DealComment> dealCommentRepo = new Repository.Repository<DealComment>(db))
                {
                    using (Repository.Repository<Proposal> proposalRepo = new Repository.Repository<Proposal>(db))
                    {
                        using (Repository.Repository<Quotation> quotationRepo = new Repository.Repository<Quotation>(db))
                        {
                            Deal deal = repo.GetById(input.Id);
                            List<DealComment> listOfDealComments = dealCommentRepo.GetAll().Where(dc => dc.DealId == deal.Id).ToList();

                            List<Proposal> listOfProposals = proposalRepo.GetAll().Where(x => x.DealId == deal.Id).ToList();
                            List<Quotation> listOfQuotations = quotationRepo.GetAll().Where(x => x.DealId == deal.Id).ToList();

                            if (listOfProposals.Count > 0 || listOfQuotations.Count > 0)
                            {
                                string message = string.Empty;

                                message += listOfProposals.Count > 0 ? "Cannot delete deal, this deal is linked to:\nProposals\n" : "Cannot delete deal, this deal is linked to:\n";

                                foreach (var item in listOfProposals)
                                {
                                    message += $"- {item.Application}\n";
                                }

                                message += listOfQuotations.Count > 0 ? "Quotations:\n" : "";

                                foreach (var item in listOfQuotations)
                                {
                                    message += $"- {item.Description}\n";
                                }

                                ufex =  new UserFriendlyException("Ooops! There is a problem.", $"{message}");

                                throw ufex;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                foreach (var item in listOfDealComments)
                                {
                                    dealCommentRepo.Delete(item);
                                    dealCommentRepo.SaveChanges();
                                }

                                if (deal != null)
                                {
                                    repo.Delete(deal);
                                    repo.SaveChanges();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            if(ufex != null)
              throw ufex;
            else
               throw new UserFriendlyException("Ooops! There is a problem.",$"Deal with Id[{input.Id}] could not be deleted.");
        }
    }
```

Abp.Boilerplate 0.9.6
Abp.EntityFramework 0.9.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permanently delete values from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50173658/8601760)

Comment: This time i want to use DataContext because the boilerplate does not solve my problem

Comment: Im assuming using the DataContext will perform the hard delete?

var employer = new Employ { Id = 1 };

ctx.Employ.Remove(employer);

ctx.SaveChanges();


and you are trying to still use ABP  but only for soft delete.
so you are trying to use the two together for the dataContext to make up for what that version of Abp cannot do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem in the past, to fix the issue i had to make sure that The version(s) of entity framework being referenced by the project(s) is the same version of entity framework for all projects in the solution.

And if required in The DataContext class make sure to enable

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

the key is to have the same names as what the ABP context is generating.